# How to use multiprocessing in a chronical order?

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, yield

I have a python script which exists of 2 processes:

1. process 1: Loading and unzipping files
2. process 2: Processing the files, doing some stuff with it.

Before implementing multiprocessing the software seemed to do its work in chronological order. Loading all the zipped files, unzipping them, then opening them to do some stuff with it.

So I have brought multiprocessing into the game and right now it seems that whilst the files are being loaded and unzipped the process of opening and doing stuff with them has already started. So there are multiple processes doing stuff at the same time. The problem is that when I run this code on big data (more then 100+ files) I get problems with concurrent file access. This results in `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:` When I run the snippet on a small data set (30 files approx.) it seems to go okay because the files are being unzipped really fast just in time process 2 starts.

**What I want:** I want to keep the multiprocessing because it is speeding up things but I want process 2 only to start if all the files have been unzipped (e.g. process 1 is done).

**This is my snippet:**

```
import os
import csv
import collections
import datetime 
import zipfile
import re
import shutil
import fnmatch
from pathlib import Path
import ntpath
import configparser
from multiprocessing import Pool

def generate_file_lists():
    # Change the following line to a real path
    data_files = 'c:\desktop\DataEnergy'
    pattern = '*.zip'
    last_root = None
    args = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_files):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            if root != last_root:
                last_root = root
                if args:
                    yield args
                    args = []
            args.append((root, filename))
    if args:
        yield args

def unzip(file_list):
    """
    file_list is a list of (root, filename) tuples where
    root is the same for all tuples.
    """
    # Change the following line to a real path:
    counter_part = 'c:\desktop\CounterPart'
    for root, filename in file_list:
        path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        date_zipped_file_s = re.search('-(.\d+)-', filename).group(1)
        date_zipped_file = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_zipped_file_s, '%Y%m%d').date()

        #Create the new directory location
        new_dir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.relpath(path, start='c:\desktop\DataEnergy'), ".."))

        #Join the directory names counter_part and create their paths.
        new = os.path.join(counter_part, new_dir)

        #Create the directories
        if (not os.path.exists(new)):
            os.makedirs(new)
        zipfile.ZipFile(path).extractall(new)

        #Get al the zipped files
        files = os.listdir(new)

        #Rename all the files in the created directories
        for file in files:
            filesplit = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))
            if not re.search(r'_\d{8}.', file):
                os.rename(os.path.join(new, file), os.path.join(new, filesplit[0]+'_'+date_zipped_file_s+filesplit[1]))

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(13)
    pool.map(unzip, generate_file_lists())
    print('the files have been unzipped!')


#Start proces 2 
all_missing_dates = ['20210701', '20210702']
missing_dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y%m%d").date() for i in all_missing_dates]

dates_to_process = []
root = Path('.\middle_stage').resolve()


at_set = {'Audi', 'Mercedes', 'Volkswagen'}

#Only read the rows if they fulfill the following conditions.
def filter_row(r, missing_date): 
    if set(row).intersection(at_set):       
        if len(r) > 24 and r[24].isdigit():
            aantal_pplgs = int(r[24])  
            date_time = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(r[0]) if len(r) > 3 else True
            condition_3 = date_time.date() == missing_date  if len(r) > 3 else True  
            
            return condition_3
    return False

#Open the files and read the rows
print("Start reading data")
data_per_date = dict()
for missing_date in missing_dates:
    print("\tReading missing date: ", missing_date)
    files=[fn for fn in (e for e in root.glob(f"**/*_{missing_date:%Y%m%d}.txt") if e.is_file())]
    if len(files) != 13:
        continue
    dates_to_process.append(missing_date)  

    vehicle_loc_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for file in files:      
        with open(file, 'r') as log_file:
            reader = csv.reader(log_file, delimiter = ',')
            next(reader) # skip header
            for row in reader:
                if filter_row(row, missing_date): 
                    print('filter_row has been executed!')

    data_per_date[missing_date] = vehicle_loc_dict
```

Comment: You need to make use of locking, to lock access to a file while another process is still working on it. Also you could use a queue system where the unzipping takes from a queue of zipped files then adds it to a queue to be processed ect, with the other threads pulling from this queue.

Comment: @Booboo, this is where I spoke to you about yesterday.

Comment: @SeanPowell Those are some good options, however I don't know how to implement it in above code..

Comment: I added an answer that should give you a general idea how to implement this, if you need anything else feel free to ask me :)

Comment: @Mediterráneo I just saw this question. I did not receive notification of your comment because I had not previously commented on *this* post; you should have written this comment on your previous question with a link to this newer question. I will take a deeper look when I have a chance.

Comment: @Booboo Thank you really looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem just seems to be the following:

If you are running under Windows (and based on the names of your directories, that seems to be the case), whenever you create a new process (here you are creating 13 new processes by creating a multiprocessing pool), the *spawn* method of creating processes is used. This means that a new, empty address space is created into which the Python interpreter is re-launched and your source program is re-executed from the top to initialize the address space by executing all statements at global scope *except* any statements that are within blocks that begin with `if __name__ == '__main__':` because in these new processes this condition will be `False`. This is also why you place code that creates new processes in such a block, i.e. so that you do not get into an recursive loop crating new processes *ad inifinitum*.

That said, your so-called *process 2* statements are at global scope not within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block and consequently they are being  executed 13 times in parallel in initializing the multiprocessing pool. But I can imagine a scenario where process 1 of the pool executes the code to no effect since nothing has been unzipped yet and then now that it has been initialized it starts to unzip a file. Meanwhile other processes in the pool start running its initialization code and there is now the conflict.

The solution is to move the process 2 code as follows:

```py
import os
import csv
import collections
import datetime 
import zipfile
import re
import shutil
import fnmatch
from pathlib import Path
import ntpath
import configparser
from multiprocessing import Pool

def generate_file_lists():
    # Change the following line to a real path
    data_files = 'c:\desktop\DataEnergy'
    pattern = '*.zip'
    last_root = None
    args = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_files):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            if root != last_root:
                last_root = root
                if args:
                    yield args
                    args = []
            args.append((root, filename))
    if args:
        yield args

def unzip(file_list):
    """
    file_list is a list of (root, filename) tuples where
    root is the same for all tuples.
    """
    # Change the following line to a real path:
    counter_part = 'c:\desktop\CounterPart'
    for root, filename in file_list:
        path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        date_zipped_file_s = re.search('-(.\d+)-', filename).group(1)
        date_zipped_file = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_zipped_file_s, '%Y%m%d').date()

        #Create the new directory location
        new_dir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.relpath(path, start='c:\desktop\DataEnergy'), ".."))

        #Join the directory names counter_part and create their paths.
        new = os.path.join(counter_part, new_dir)

        #Create the directories
        if (not os.path.exists(new)):
            os.makedirs(new)
        zipfile.ZipFile(path).extractall(new)

        #Get al the zipped files
        files = os.listdir(new)

        #Rename all the files in the created directories
        for file in files:
            filesplit = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))
            if not re.search(r'_\d{8}.', file):
                os.rename(os.path.join(new, file), os.path.join(new, filesplit[0]+'_'+date_zipped_file_s+filesplit[1]))

    return False

def process1():
    pool = Pool(13)
    pool.map(unzip, generate_file_lists())
    print('the files have been unzipped!')

#Only read the rows if they fulfill the following conditions.
def filter_row(r, missing_date): 
    if set(row).intersection(at_set):       
        if len(r) > 24 and r[24].isdigit():
            aantal_pplgs = int(r[24])  
            date_time = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(r[0]) if len(r) > 3 else True
            condition_3 = date_time.date() == missing_date  if len(r) > 3 else True  
            
            return condition_3

def process2():   
    #Start proces 2 
    all_missing_dates = ['20210701', '20210702']
    missing_dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y%m%d").date() for i in all_missing_dates]
    
    dates_to_process = []
    root = Path('.\middle_stage').resolve()   
    
    at_set = {'Audi', 'Mercedes', 'Volkswagen'}
    
    #Open the files and read the rows
    print("Start reading data")
    data_per_date = dict()
    for missing_date in missing_dates:
        print("\tReading missing date: ", missing_date)
        files=[fn for fn in (e for e in root.glob(f"**/*_{missing_date:%Y%m%d}.txt") if e.is_file())]
        if len(files) != 13:
            continue
        dates_to_process.append(missing_date)  
    
        vehicle_loc_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for file in files:      
            with open(file, 'r') as log_file:
                reader = csv.reader(log_file, delimiter = ',')
                next(reader) # skip header
                for row in reader:
                    if filter_row(row, missing_date): 
                        print('filter_row has been executed!')
    
        data_per_date[missing_date] = vehicle_loc_dict
        
def main():
    process1()
    process2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: and what if I also have a process 3? Does that one also needs an indentation under the `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: Yes. I would think it would be best however to create functions `process1`, `process2` and `process3` and then just have in your `if __name__ == '__main__':` block calls to the 3 functions is succession. Or better yet have it just call function `main`, which calls the three process functions. See the updated answer.

Comment: So very simply said (sorry English is not my native language). Everything outside the if __name__ block is being executed in parallel with that which is inside the block. That results in two different processes running near each other instead of after each other.

Comment: One more question, what if I want to implement multiprocessing for process 2 also? Do I need to create new file lists for example?

Comment: If you wanted to process the same exact zip files a second time than in function `main` you should allocate the multiprocessing poo and do: `file_lists = list(generate_file_lists())` then pass `pool` and  `file_lists` to both `process1` and `process2` so that both the multiprocessing pool and the lists of files can be reused without having to be re-created just for the sake of efficiency. Otherwise, you would have to call `generate_file_lists()` a second time and re-walk the directory to rebuild the same lists. (more...)

Comment: But `process2` does not seem to process the same file lists, or am I missing something? In which case just create the `pool` in `main` and pass that to both functions.

Comment: can you help with this one bro? Really appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69173514/how-to-use-multiprocessing-in-current-python-application

Comment: see my last question bro. I added some more things to your code but I received a WinError.

Comment: @Mediterráneo You have me confused as to which question since you have posted your question here. I think it best to now post a *new* question with the "new things" you have added along with a stack trace.

Comment: it is a new question. Im 100% you know the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69194862/how-to-solve-the-winerror-when-multithreading

Answer (score 1):

## Main Thread

In the main thread we need to setup the queues and add the zipped files to the queues

```
import threading
import queue 

zippedQueue = queue.Queue()
unzippedQueue = queue.Queue()
zippedLock = threading.Lock()

for file in files:
   zippedQueue.put(file)
```

## Worker Thread

```
class ChiSquaredThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        unzipFile()

# add all your zipped files to the zippedQueue 
def unzipFile():
   zippedLock.acquire()
   if not zippedQueue.empty():
      zipped = zippedQueue.get()
      zippedLock.release()
      # unzip the zipped file here
      # add unziped file to queue
      unzipedQueue.put(unzippedFile)
```

then create a similar block as the worker thread block that does the same steps and processes the file. This sample block in the worker thread should guide you on that

Comment: Okay this seems as a good first step. However, I struggle to find the relation between your snippet and mine. So how do I add my zipped files to the `zippedQueue`

Comment: loop through all your files in the main thread and use `zippedQueue.put(file)` then have your unzip thread run the processFile() function and add the section where you unzip the file. Then create a similar function for processing the file.

Comment: With main thread you mean `def processFile` ? Im new to this processing/threading but I really want to understand it.

Comment: @Mediterráneo i edited it now see if that helps you

Comment: so what will we do first? Adding the files to the queue or unzipping them? Also which part of my snippet has to be removed to make place for yours?

Comment: you add the files to a queue first, then you add your code for unzipping to where the comment is. This will be your unzipping thread. Then you duplicate this, and modify it to take from the unzipped queue and instead of unzipping make it process the files and finally add to wherever you want to store processed files this will be your processing thread

Comment: Okay I will try and implement it and I would like you to take a loot at it after I'm finished. Is there some other platform we can chat in or something? Like Slack for example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236838/discussion-between-sean-powell-and-mediterraneo).

Comment: Im in the chat bro, where are you?