# How to use multiprocessing in current Python application?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, config, mysql-python

I have an application that is reading thousand of files from different directories, it reads them, does some processing with them and then sends the data to a database. I have 1 problem, it takes approx. 1 hour to finish all the files from 1 directory, I have 19 directories (which could be more in the future). Right now its doing it directory after directory, I want to run everything parallel so I speed up things.

**This is my code:**

```
import mysql.connector
import csv
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import ntpath
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()                         
config.read('C:\Desktop\Energy\file_cfg.ini')

source = config['PATHS']['source']
archive = config['PATHS']['archive']

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host= config['DB']['host'],
        user = config['DB']['user'],
        passwd = config['DB']['passwd'],
        database= config['DB']['database']
    )

cursor = mydb.cursor()
select_antenna = "SELECT * FROM `antenna`"
cursor.execute(select_antenna)

mp_mysql = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
mp_server = os.listdir(source)

# microbeats clean.
cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE microbeats")

for mp in mp_mysql:
    if mp in mp_server:
        subdir_paths = os.path.join(source, mp)

        for file in os.listdir(subdir_paths):
            file_paths = os.path.join(subdir_paths, file)
                        
            cr_time_s = os.path.getctime(file_paths)
            cr_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(cr_time_s))
                        
        all_file_paths = [os.path.join(subdir_paths, f) for f in os.listdir(subdir_paths)]
        full_file_paths = [p for p in all_file_paths if os.path.getsize(p) > 0] #<----- Control empty files.
                
        if full_file_paths != []:
            newest_file_paths = max(full_file_paths, key=os.path.getctime)
                        
            for file in all_file_paths:
                if file == newest_file_paths and os.path.getctime(newest_file_paths) < time.time() - 120: 
                    with open(file, 'rt') as f:
                        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter ='\t')
                        line_data0 = list()
                        col = next(reader)
                        
                        for line in reader:
                            line.insert(0, mp)
                            line.insert(1, cr_time)
                            if line != []: #<----- Control empty directories.
                                line_data0.append(line)
                            
                                                                                                                                              
                        q1 = ("INSERT INTO microbeats"
                                     "(`antenna`,`datetime`,`system`,`item`,`event`, `status`, `accident`)"
                                     "VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s)")

                        for line in line_data0:
                             cursor.execute(q1, line)
```

Comment: You have both CPU-bound and I/O-bound code here. Yes, multiprocessing will speed this up, but there are some design issues here. Try turning the for-loop `for file in all_file_paths` into a function, then use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map` to execute the function. If that speeds it up enough then call it a day. Otherwise, you'll need to tackle your design issues by preprocessing your queries (potentially with concurrency) and then executing the queries concurrently with threads.

Comment: Firstly, you probably don't really need multi-processing as multi-threading is fine for this type of application. For efficiency you should look into execute_many() rather than executing lots of discrete inserts. Use connection pooling because MySQL connections are not thread safe. Don't forget to commit your changes!

Comment: Actually, without an attempt to use `multiprocessing`, this question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please give it a shot, post your code, expected result and actual result, or repost to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Can you guys show me what you mean by showing it in code please? That also gives me the opportunity to accept your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using multiprocessing where each process has its own connection to the database. I have done the minimal changes to your code in an attempt to process directories in parallel. However, I am not sure if a variable such as `subdir_paths` is correctly named since the "s" at the end of its name implies that it contains multiple path names.

The reason why it has been suggested that this question is better suited for Code Review is because presumably you have an already-working program and you are only looking for a performance improvement (of course, that applies to a great percentage of the question posted on SO that are tagged with `multiprocessing`). That type of question is supposed to be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

```py
import mysql.connector
import csv
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import ntpath
import configparser
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('C:\Desktop\Energy\file_cfg.ini')

source = config['PATHS']['source']
archive = config['PATHS']['archive']

def get_connnection():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host= config['DB']['host'],
            user = config['DB']['user'],
            passwd = config['DB']['passwd'],
            database= config['DB']['database']
        )
    return mydb

def get_mp_list():
    select_antenna = "SELECT * FROM `antenna`"
    mydb = get_connection()
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.execute(select_antenna)

    mp_mysql = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
    mp_server = os.listdir(source)

    # microbeats clean.
    cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE microbeats")
    mydb.commit()
    mydb.close()

    mp_list = [mp for mp in mp_mysql if mp in mp_server]
    return mp_list

def process_mp(mp):
    subdir_paths = os.path.join(source, mp)
    for file in os.listdir(subdir_paths):
        file_paths = os.path.join(subdir_paths, file)

        cr_time_s = os.path.getctime(file_paths)
        cr_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(cr_time_s))

    all_file_paths = [os.path.join(subdir_paths, f) for f in os.listdir(subdir_paths)]
    full_file_paths = [p for p in all_file_paths if os.path.getsize(p) > 0] #<----- Control empty files.

    if full_file_paths != []:
        newest_file_paths = max(full_file_paths, key=os.path.getctime)

        mydb = get_connection()
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        did_insert = False
        q1 = ("INSERT INTO microbeats"
                     "(`antenna`,`datetime`,`system`,`item`,`event`, `status`, `accident`)"
                     "VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s)")
        for file in all_file_paths:
            if file == newest_file_paths and os.path.getctime(newest_file_paths) < time.time() - 120:
                with open(file, 'rt') as f:
                    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter ='\t')
                    line_data0 = list()
                    col = next(reader)

                    for line in reader:
                        line.insert(0, mp)
                        line.insert(1, cr_time)
                        if line != []: #<----- Control empty directories.
                            line_data0.append(line)

                    if line_data0:
                        cursor.executemany(q1, line_data0)
                        did_insert = True
        if did_insert:
            mydb.commit()
        mydb.close()

def main():
    mp_list = get_mp_list()
    pool = Pool(min(cpu_count(), len(mp_list)))
    results = pool.imap_unordered(process_mp, mp_list)
    while True:
        try:
            result = next(results)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists`

Comment: @Mediterráneo Where is the error? I can't run the code myself for obvious reasons.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/data/Energy/Desktop/test_booboo.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/data/Energy/Desktop/test_booboo.py", line 79, in main
    all_subdir_paths = get_all_subdir_paths()
  File "c:/data/Energy/Desktop/test_booboo.py", line 28, in get_all_subdir_paths
    cursor.execute(select_antennas)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 232, in execute
    if not self._cnx:
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists`

Comment: Try the updated code, although I may have moved the error elsewhere. If so, I have one more thing to try.

Comment: mp is not defined, but thats NOT giving an error. However, it seems like nothing is getting inserted into the database. Table microbeats is still empty after i run the code (i did not receive any errors)

Comment: Did the original code work? Is autocommit set to True for the connection or do you need to explicitly do commits?

Comment: I have updated the code in an attempt to get rid of the `mp` not defined error.

Comment: Ah forgot to place the `mydb.commit()` and `mydb.close()` lines. Where do I need to put them? I have placed them as last line of `process_mp` but that did not work either...

Comment: I updated the code to add the necessary commits. I also added a `mydb.close()` in `get_mp_list` but a call to `close()` cannot be added elsewhere since the connection must stay open for each process in the pool. The connections used by each process in the pool will be closed when they are garbage collected at the end of the program. Commits are required whenever a table is modified (truncate, delete, insert, update, etc.)

Comment: Hmm still dont understand whats going wrong, Im running the exact same code as you. I debugged it, I can see there is data but when I look to table `microbeats` its empty. No errors nothing.........

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237100/discussion-between-booboo-and-mediterraneo).

Comment: I have answered in the discussion.