# How to solve the WinError when Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have added the multiprocessing part to my code but I receive below error. I dont know what is wrong, I have placed everything inside the `__main__` block as I though that would solve the issue, however that did not work.

```
[WinError None] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\data\\Energy\\Desktop\\Source\\d\\New Text Document.txt' -> 'c:\\data\\Energy\\Desktop\\Source\\d\\New Text Document.txt'
```

**This is my code:**

```
import mysql.connector
import csv
import os
import time
import re
from datetime import datetime
import ntpath
import configparser
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(r'Energy_cfg.ini')

source = config['PATHS']['source']
archive = config['PATHS']['archive']

def get_connection():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host= config['DB']['host'],
            user = config['DB']['user'],
            passwd = config['DB']['passwd'],
            database= config['DB']['database']
        )
    return mydb

def get_mp_list():
    select_antennas = "SELECT * FROM `antennas`"
    mydb = get_connection()
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.execute(select_antennas)

    mp_mysql = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
    mp_server = os.listdir(source)

    # microbeats clean.
    cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE microbeats")
    mydb.commit()
    mydb.close()

    mp_list = [mp for mp in mp_mysql if mp in mp_server]
    return mp_list

def process_mp(mp):
    subdir_paths = os.path.join(source, mp)
    for file in os.listdir(subdir_paths):
        file_paths = os.path.join(subdir_paths, file)

        cr_time_s = os.path.getctime(file_paths)
        cr_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(cr_time_s))

    all_file_paths = [os.path.join(subdir_paths, f) for f in os.listdir(subdir_paths)]
    full_file_paths = [p for p in all_file_paths if os.path.getsize(p) > 0] #<----- Control empty files.

    if full_file_paths != []:
        newest_file_paths = max(full_file_paths, key=os.path.getctime)

        mydb = get_connection()
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        did_insert = False
        for file in all_file_paths:
            if file == newest_file_paths and os.path.getctime(newest_file_paths) < time.time() - 120:
                with open(file, 'rt') as f:
                    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter ='\t')
                    line_data0 = list()
                    col = next(reader)

                    for line in reader:
                        line.insert(0, mp)
                        line.insert(1, cr_time)
                        if line != []: #<----- Control empty directories.
                            line_data0.append(line)

                        q1 = ("INSERT INTO microbeats"
                                     "(`antena`,`datetime`,`system`,`cave`,`Color`, `nature`, `options`)"
                                     "VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s)")

                    for line in line_data0:
                         cursor.execute(q1, line)
                         did_insert = True

                    for i in line_data0:
                            if 'AI stats' in i:
                                list_z = [float(x.split(":")[1]) for x in i[6].split(",")] 
                                for variable in list_z:
                                    dc1 = list_z[0]
                                    sd1 = list_z[1]
                                    dc1max = list_z[2]
                                    dc1min = list_z[3]
                                    dc2 = list_z[4]
                                    sd2 = list_z[5]
                                    dc2max = list_z[6]
                                    dc2min = list_z[7]
                                    ac = list_z[8]
                                    sd3 = list_z[9]
                                    acmax= list_z[10]
                                    acmin = list_z[11] 
                                                                                               
                                red_zone = 1
                                
                                if dc1min <50 or dc2min <50:
                                    red_zone == 1

                                if dc1max >3000 or dc2max >3000:
                                    red_zone ==1
                                    
                                if dc1 <1 or dc2 <1:
                                    red_zone == 1

                                if ac >= -1 or ac <= 1:
                                    red_zone ==1

                                if acmin < -700:
                                    red_zone ==1

                                if acmax > 700: 
                                    red_zone ==1
                                    
                                if red_zone  ==1:
                                    q2 = ("Update microbeats SET `nature` = 'SIZED' WHERE cave = 'AI stats' AND antena = '{}'".format(mp)) 
                                    cursor.execute(q2) #<-----updaten microbeats
    
                    hb_name = ntpath.basename(newest_file_paths) 
                    cur_time = datetime.now()
                    cur_time_m = cur_time.strftime("%M")
                    
                    md_time = os.path.getctime(newest_file_paths)
                    md_time_m = time.strftime("%M", time.localtime(md_time))
                    l_heared = int(cur_time_m) - int(md_time_m) 
                    
                    line_data1 = list()
                    line_data1.insert(0, hb_name)
                    line_data1.insert(1, l_heared)
                                            
                    statinfo = os.stat(newest_file_paths)
                    
                    if statinfo.st_size < 400:
                        line_data1.insert(2, 'Corrupt')
                    else:
                        line_data1.insert(2, '-_-')
                        
                    line_data10 = list()
                    line_data10.append(line_data1)
                                            
                    q3 = "UPDATE antennas SET lsbeat = %s, lastheared = %s, alarm =%s WHERE `antennas`.`antena` = '{}'".format(mp)
                    
                    for line in line_data10:
                        cursor.execute(q3, line) #<-----aanvullen antennas
                        
                    cur_time = datetime.now()
                    cur_time_f = cur_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  
                    
                    line_data2 = list()
                    line_data2.append(cur_time_f)  

                    
                    q4 = ("UPDATE leaving_time SET Datetime = %s") 
                    
                    cursor.execute(q4, line_data2)  #<-----vullen leaving_time
                                                                     
                    q5 = ("INSERT INTO microbeats (antena, datetime, `system`, Color, cave, `nature`, options) (SELECT antena, datetime, `system`, 's', 'TDiff', `nature`, options FROM microbeats WHERE Color = 'M' AND cave = 'tijd' AND antena = '{}')".format(mp))                
                    cursor.execute(q5) #<-----updaten microbeats

                    sys_t_l = []       
                    for i in line_data0:
                        if 'Tijd' in i:
                            
                            sys_t = re.search('Organic Sys:(.+?),', i[6]).group(1)
                            sys_t = sys_t.replace('-', '')
                            sys_t_l.append(sys_t)

                            for var in sys_t_l:
                                dt_sys_t = datetime.strptime(var, " %Y%m%d%H%M%S") 
                                
                                cur_time = datetime.now()
                                                                    
                                time_delta = (dt_sys_t - cur_time)
                                total_seconds = time_delta.total_seconds()
                                minutes = total_seconds/60

                                if minutes > 90:
                                    q6 = ("Update microbeats SET `nature` = 'SIZED' WHERE cave = 'TDiff' AND antena = '{}'".format(mp)) 
                                    cursor.execute(q6)
                                 
                    
                    for file in all_file_paths:
                        if os.path.getctime(file) > time.time() - 120:
                            continue 
                        if os.path.getsize(file) == 0:
                            dst_root = source
                            dst_path_2 = os.path.join(dst_root, mp, os.path.basename(file))
                            os.rename(file, dst_path_2)
                            
                    for file in full_file_paths:
                        if os.path.getctime(file) > time.time() - 120:
                            continue 
                                                   
                        if file == newest_file_paths :
                            dst_root = source
                            dst_path_3 = os.path.join(dst_root, mp, os.path.basename(file))
                            os.rename(file, dst_path_3)
                        else:
                            date_archive = os.path.join(archive, datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m'), mp)
                            dst_root = date_archive
                            if not os.path.exists(dst_root):
                                os.makedirs(dst_root)
                            dst_path_4 = os.path.join(dst_root, os.path.basename(file))
                            os.replace(file, dst_path_4)   
                    
        if did_insert:
            mydb.commit()
        mydb.close()


def main():
    mp_list = get_mp_list()
    pool = Pool(min(cpu_count(), len(mp_list)))
    results = pool.imap_unordered(process_mp, mp_list)
    while True:
        try:
            result = next(results)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: (1) It *appears* to me that the renames `os.rename(file, dst_path_2))` and `os.rename(file, dst_path_3)` are just renaming the file to itself and have no effect. (2) The check `if file == newest_file_paths :` wil never be `True` because `newest_file_paths` has the owning directory, `subdir_paths` joined to it whereas `file` does not. (3) If these files are ever modified then you might wish to use `os.path.getmtime` instead of `os.path.getctime`.

Comment: @Booboo but that does not solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comments to your question above. It's still not clear where the error is occurring so I have added a stack trace and for my own edification some additional statements with `#Booboo` added to the end, which you should eventually remove. I have also modified the commit processing necessitated by your additional SQL statements.

```py
import mysql.connector
import csv
import os
import time
import re
from datetime import datetime
import ntpath
import configparser
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import traceback

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(r'Energy_cfg.ini')

source = config['PATHS']['source']
archive = config['PATHS']['archive']

def get_connection():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host= config['DB']['host'],
            user = config['DB']['user'],
            passwd = config['DB']['passwd'],
            database= config['DB']['database']
        )
    return mydb

def get_mp_list():
    select_antennas = "SELECT * FROM `antennas`"
    mydb = get_connection()
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.execute(select_antennas)

    mp_mysql = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
    mp_server = os.listdir(source)

    # microbeats clean.
    cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE microbeats")
    mydb.commit()
    mydb.close()

    mp_list = [mp for mp in mp_mysql if mp in mp_server]
    return mp_list

def process_mp(mp):
    subdir_paths = os.path.join(source, mp)
    for file in os.listdir(subdir_paths):
        file_paths = os.path.join(subdir_paths, file)

        cr_time_s = os.path.getctime(file_paths)
        cr_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(cr_time_s))

    all_file_paths = [os.path.join(subdir_paths, f) for f in os.listdir(subdir_paths)]
    full_file_paths = [p for p in all_file_paths if os.path.getsize(p) > 0] #<----- Control empty files.

    if full_file_paths != []:
        newest_file_paths = max(full_file_paths, key=os.path.getctime)

        mydb = get_connection()
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        for file in all_file_paths:
            if file == newest_file_paths and os.path.getctime(newest_file_paths) < time.time() - 120:
                with open(file, 'rt') as f:
                    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter ='\t')
                    line_data0 = list()
                    col = next(reader)

                    for line in reader:
                        line.insert(0, mp)
                        line.insert(1, cr_time)
                        if line != []: #<----- Control empty directories.
                            line_data0.append(line)

                        q1 = ("INSERT INTO microbeats"
                                     "(`antena`,`datetime`,`system`,`cave`,`Color`, `nature`, `options`)"
                                     "VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s)")

                    for line in line_data0:
                         cursor.execute(q1, line)

                    for i in line_data0:
                            if 'AI stats' in i:
                                list_z = [float(x.split(":")[1]) for x in i[6].split(",")]
                                for variable in list_z:
                                    dc1 = list_z[0]
                                    sd1 = list_z[1]
                                    dc1max = list_z[2]
                                    dc1min = list_z[3]
                                    dc2 = list_z[4]
                                    sd2 = list_z[5]
                                    dc2max = list_z[6]
                                    dc2min = list_z[7]
                                    ac = list_z[8]
                                    sd3 = list_z[9]
                                    acmax= list_z[10]
                                    acmin = list_z[11]

                                red_zone = 1

                                if dc1min <50 or dc2min <50:
                                    red_zone == 1

                                if dc1max >3000 or dc2max >3000:
                                    red_zone ==1

                                if dc1 <1 or dc2 <1:
                                    red_zone == 1

                                if ac >= -1 or ac <= 1:
                                    red_zone ==1

                                if acmin < -700:
                                    red_zone ==1

                                if acmax > 700:
                                    red_zone ==1

                                if red_zone  ==1:
                                    q2 = ("Update microbeats SET `nature` = 'SIZED' WHERE cave = 'AI stats' AND antena = '{}'".format(mp))
                                    cursor.execute(q2) #<-----updaten microbeats

                    hb_name = ntpath.basename(newest_file_paths)
                    cur_time = datetime.now()
                    cur_time_m = cur_time.strftime("%M")

                    md_time = os.path.getctime(newest_file_paths)
                    md_time_m = time.strftime("%M", time.localtime(md_time))
                    l_heared = int(cur_time_m) - int(md_time_m)

                    line_data1 = list()
                    line_data1.insert(0, hb_name)
                    line_data1.insert(1, l_heared)

                    statinfo = os.stat(newest_file_paths)

                    if statinfo.st_size < 400:
                        line_data1.insert(2, 'Corrupt')
                    else:
                        line_data1.insert(2, '-_-')

                    line_data10 = list()
                    line_data10.append(line_data1)

                    q3 = "UPDATE antennas SET lsbeat = %s, lastheared = %s, alarm =%s WHERE `antennas`.`antena` = '{}'".format(mp)

                    if line_data10:
                        cursor.executemany(q3, line_data10)

                    cur_time = datetime.now()
                    cur_time_f = cur_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

                    line_data2 = list()
                    line_data2.append(cur_time_f)


                    q4 = ("UPDATE leaving_time SET Datetime = %s")

                    cursor.execute(q4, line_data2)  #<-----vullen leaving_time

                    q5 = ("INSERT INTO microbeats (antena, datetime, `system`, Color, cave, `nature`, options) (SELECT antena, datetime, `system`, 's', 'TDiff', `nature`, options FROM microbeats WHERE Color = 'M' AND cave = 'tijd' AND antena = '{}')".format(mp))
                    cursor.execute(q5) #<-----updaten microbeats

                    sys_t_l = []
                    for i in line_data0:
                        if 'Tijd' in i:

                            sys_t = re.search('Organic Sys:(.+?),', i[6]).group(1)
                            sys_t = sys_t.replace('-', '')
                            sys_t_l.append(sys_t)

                            for var in sys_t_l:
                                dt_sys_t = datetime.strptime(var, " %Y%m%d%H%M%S")

                                cur_time = datetime.now()

                                time_delta = (dt_sys_t - cur_time)
                                total_seconds = time_delta.total_seconds()
                                minutes = total_seconds/60

                                if minutes > 90:
                                    q6 = ("Update microbeats SET `nature` = 'SIZED' WHERE cave = 'TDiff' AND antena = '{}'".format(mp))
                                    cursor.execute(q6)

                    for file in full_file_paths:
                        if os.path.getctime(file) <= time.time() - 120 and file != newest_file_paths:
                            date_archive = os.path.join(archive, datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m'), mp)
                            dst_root = date_archive
                            if not os.path.exists(dst_root):
                                os.makedirs(dst_root, exist_ok=True)
                            dst_path_4 = os.path.join(dst_root, os.path.basename(file))
                            os.replace(file, dst_path_4)

        mydb.commit()
        mydb.close()


def main():
    mp_list = get_mp_list()
    pool = Pool(min(cpu_count(), len(mp_list)))
    results = pool.imap_unordered(process_mp, mp_list)
    while True:
        try:
            result = next(results)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except BaseException as e:
            traceback.print_exc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `PermissionError: [WinError None] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\data\\Energy\\Desktop\\Source\\d\\New Text Document.txt' -> 'c:\\data\\Energy\\Desktop\\Source\\d\\New Text Document.txt'`

Comment: Doesn't it give line numbers?

Comment: `in main
    result = next(results)` . This line

Comment: What are the other lines in the source file it shows? I just need the numbers assuming you haven't modified anything.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/data/Energy/Desktop/Python Microsoft Visual Studio/heartbeat/bobo_v8.py", line 225, in main
    result = next(results)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 748, in next
    raise value
PermissionError: [WinError None] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\data\\Energy\\Desktop\\Source\\d\\New Text Document.txt' -> 'c:\\data\\A414405\\Desktop\\Source\\d\\New Text Document.txt'`

Comment: line 225, `main result` is the only line it is showing.

Comment: That's my line 226. What have you changed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237147/discussion-between-booboo-and-mediterraneo).

Comment: I examined your whole code, I understand it for 95%, just a few short questions if I may ask them to understand it 100%. May I ask them in the https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237147/discussion-between-booboo-and-mediterraneo